# How can I calculate average interatomic distance between all identical elements in supercell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, software

Good afternoon! Maybe someone came across, I want to know the average interatomic distance between all identical elements in some supercell. In Vesta or a similar program, it shows only one piece at a time. Maybe someone knows in what program it is worth cranking? There probably is, but I couldn't find it on the forum. If it isn't possible in simple way, I want get all lengths.

Comment: Also I tried with Avogadro, but it only gave a list of interatomic distances without a possibility to calculate the average value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but probably you might want to look at [Olex2](https://www.olexsys.org/olex2/) and its [envi](https://www.olexsys.org/olex2/docs/reference/commands/envi/) command in combination with `sel $<atom_label>`. Note that [Chemistry.SE and Stack Exchange sites in general are not forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).

Comment: I also suspect in Avogadro 1, that the distances don't consider unit cell boundaries. If you submit it as a feature request to the [Avogadro forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) it should be fairly easy to add, although that might not help in the immediate moment.